# Click not working with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to KnockoutJS and below is my code. The click event is not responding as the button is not responding. Can someone tell where I'm going wrong.

I googled for solution but could not find any help.

HTML Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped b-t text-sm table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>GM</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
          <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.user_fname + ' ' + $data.user_lname">
            </td>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-bind="click: $data.removeUser">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
<script>
  getUsers();
</script>
```

JS Code:

```
function getUsers()
{
 $.ajax({
      url: "api/example/func/format/json",
      dataType: 'json'
 }).done(function(data){
 users = ko.observableArray(data);
 ko.applyBindings(users);
 }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
      alert(jqXHR.status)
 });
}

function removeUser() {
 console.log('userRemoved');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In next line `ko.applyBindings(users);` you bind your variable `users` to all html document as a context. And when you use $data in html it's actually will be that object `users`.

When you do `foreach` (as you can simply guess) your context became one of the elements in `users` array. And when later you are calling `data-bind="click: $data.removeUser"` knockout try to find `removeUser` function in your current context i.e. `user[i]` object. But it's not there, because according to your js - it's defined in global score

Comment: I understood your explanation. So how do I fix this?

Comment: create a object which will be wrapper for an observable array like this: `var ctx = { users: users, removeUser: function() {console.log('userRemoved');}; }` and use it in the binding `ko.applyBindings(ctx);`